# What are the pros and cons of impl TryFrom<Bar> for Foo vs impl From<Bar> for Result<Foo, ()> for fallible conversions?

Tags: rust

Starting from Rust 1.34, we can write fallible conversions between types by implementing the `TryFrom` trait:

```
struct Foo(i32);
struct Bar;

impl TryFrom<Bar> for Foo {
    type Error = ();
    fn try_from(_b: Bar) -> Result<Foo, ()> {
        Ok(Foo(42))
    }
}
```

In Rust 1.41, the orphan rule has been relaxed so we can also write:

```
struct Foo(i32);
struct Bar;

impl From<Bar> for Result<Foo, ()> {
    fn from(_b: Bar) -> Result<Foo, ()> {
        Ok(Foo(42))
    }
}
```

According to [this trial](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=38dd5569bab6ff5d4c22bbf748c487ad) both solutions seem to work equally well.

What are the pros and cons of having either or both approach? How to choose from the two?

This question is important to the ecosystem. For example, a crate writer needs advice on whether to support `TryFrom`, `From` or both. A macro writer will need to know if it needs to handle both cases, etc. This depends on the status of the ecosystem today, and can't be answered easily.

Comment: more readable ? Previous orphan rule (by the way I didn't know) ? From is expected to not fail whereas try from is expected to have possible error.

Comment: In regards to the orphan rule, the previous versions didn't allow writing that `impl` since both `From` and `Result` are not defined in your crate. But now this is relaxed for the case that `Result<Foo,_>` is allowed as long as you are in the crate defines `Foo`. Check https://blog.rust-lang.org/2020/01/30/Rust-1.41.0.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `TryFrom`, the error is an associated type—it is fixed by the type `Bar`. This is not the case for `From`, and indeed you could implement `From` for more than one error type. Unless you intend to do that (which is rather strange), you should stick to `TryFrom`.