# How do I use the blanket Into trait implementation to convert back to the original type?

Tags: enums, rust, type-conversion, traits

The documentation for the [`From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html) trait has the following to say about the trait itself and any possible failures:

> One should always prefer implementing `From` over `Into` because implementing `From` automatically provides one with an implementation of `Into` thanks to the blanket implementation in the standard library.

and

> Note: This trait must not fail. If the conversion can fail, use `TryFrom`.

I have the following `From` implementation for turning integers into Roman numerals:

```rust
/// ### UpperRoman
/// Upper-case Roman numerals. The `None` variant is for handling invalid conversions.
pub enum UpperRoman {
    M,
    CM,
    D,
    CD,
    C,
    XC,
    L,
    XL,
    X,
    IX,
    V,
    IV,
    I,
    None,
}

impl From<u32> for UpperRoman {
    /// ### from
    /// Converts a `u32` to an `UpperRoman` numeral variant.
    fn from(numeral: u32) -> Self {
        match numeral {
            1000 => Self::M,
            900 => Self::CM,
            500 => Self::D,
            400 => Self::CD,
            100 => Self::C,
            90 => Self::XC,
            50 => Self::L,
            40 => Self::XL,
            10 => Self::X,
            9 => Self::IX,
            5 => Self::V,
            4 => Self::IV,
            1 => Self::I,
            _ => Self::None,
        }
    }
}
```

There are only a few valid cases. For any invalid input, I have defined a variant `UpperRoman::None`, which implies that there is no Roman numeral matching the given input. This takes care of any failure cases, so the requirements set in the documentation are met.

What if I wanted to use the automatically generated `Into`-trait implementation to convert a Roman numeral back into an integer? How does the `UpperRoman::into` function handle the `UpperRoman::None` case? Is my only option to match against the possible input of `UpperRoman::into` to make sure it isn't the `UpperRoman::None` variant before calling the function?

Comment: There is no auto-generated implementation for `Into<u32> for UpperRoman`. There will be an implementation of `Into<UpperRoman> for u32`, i.e. for the same conversion you've implemented manually.

Comment: "automatically generated `Into`-trait implementation to convert a Roman numeral back into an integer" → There is no such thing. When you define `From<u32> for UpperRoman`, you get automatically `Into<UpperRoman> for u32`, not `Into<u32> for UpperRoman`. `From` doesn't need to be bijective as you've discovered, and doesn't need to be implemented the way you did so the compiler can't guess how to generate the other way.

Comment: It would be much more idiomatic not to have a `None` case in `UpperRoman`, and instead use `TryFrom` and `Option<UpperRoman>` when the value could be `None`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a mix-up here. Given your implementation of `From<u32> for UpperRoman`, the compiler *will not give you the **opposite conversion** automatically* (i.e. from `UpperRoman` to `u32`). Rather, it will give you the *dual implementation*: `Into<UpperRoman> for u32`, which semantically has the same direction. This blanket implementation of `Into` would allow the programmer to write either one of these:

```rust
let c = UpperRoman::from(100);
let c: UpperRoman = 100.into();
```

With that said, this means that you need to work your way on making an opposite conversion that makes sense. In this case, it would be better to assume that the conversion from `u32` to `UpperRoman` is a fallible conversion, because not all integer numbers map to a single Roman numeral.
This would also allow you to drop the `None` variant, which only served as a "null" value that is pretty much unwanted, and can be added to any type via `Option` anyway.

```rust
use std::convert::TryFrom;

pub enum UpperRoman {
    M,
    CM,
    D,
    CD,
    C,
    XC,
    L,
    XL,
    X,
    IX,
    V,
    IV,
    I,
}

impl TryFrom<u32> for UpperRoman {
    type Error = &'static str;

    fn try_from(numeral: u32) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        match numeral {
            1000 => Ok(Self::M),
            900 => Ok(Self::CM),
            // expand the rest here
            4 => Ok(Self::IV),
            1 => Ok(Self::I),
            _ => Err("that is no good!"),
        }
    }
}
```

(The creation of a better error type for this conversion is left as an exercise to the reader.)

With that done, converting `UpperRoman` to `u32` is trivial:

```rust
impl From<UpperRoman> for u32 {
    fn from(v: UpperRoman) -> Self {
        Self::M => 1000,
        // ... expand the remaining variants exhaustively here, no None
    }
}
```

See also:

- [What are the pros and cons of impl TryFrom<Bar> for Foo vs impl From<Bar> for Result<Foo, ()> for fallible conversions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62566447)